# Laravel 5.4 - Use Controller outside of a route

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I haven't been able to use controllers outside of routes.

I want to be able to access a column in a row, in my users table. I want to get the users ID and assign it to a variable. But I don't want to use a route because this isn't for a page; it's for my master layout file.

I have a column called "admin". If this is equal to 1, I want to use @if in my menu bar to display a link to the admin control panel. But to get the admin column I need to be able to access the users table.

I've tried doing this by using jQuery to assign the user ID to a variable on page load:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 

    get('userController@index');

    $userID = {{ $user->id }};
    console.log($userID);

})
```

I also tried

```
$(window).load(function(){ 

    Route::get('userController@index');

    $userID = {{ $user->id }};
    console.log($userID);

})
```

Essentially, I don't know how to access Models or Controllers without routes, eg:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

The Laravel error I get is

```
Undefined variable: user
```

I know that I'm not accessing the admin column here, I know how to do that once I can access the user table.

Answer (score 2):

The view not access controller directly. In other words, the view is used for controller to generate html to f2e (client browser), so view must get the variables from controller (see below image).[image]

'Use Controller outside of a route', it used for controller helper like services. For example, if the controller is to large, it can divide to small functions to services. Or, multiple controllers use same common utilities, it also can divide to services. The small functions or same common utilities are only called by controllers without routing.

You should access admin from model for each controller that use master layout file. For example, if home and user view contain master layout file, then the two view must get the admin variable from it controller...

- Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
- Route::get('/user', 'HomeController@user');

controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function index(){
            return view('home', ['admin' =>User::findOrFail($current_user.id).admin]);
    }
    public function user(){
            return view('user', ['admin' => User::findOrFail($current_user.id).admin]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand that a little better now, but I'm still not sure how I go about achieving what I want

Comment: You should access admin from model for each controller that use master layout file. For example, if /home routes use HomeController@index, and index return some views. You should access admin in  HomeController@index and pass it to view.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I understand a little more after every edit!

How do I get that Controller code into *every single* view I have? I don't want to have to add "HomeController@index" to every single view. My master sidebar is on every single page, it's like a header.

Comment: How do I run a function in a controller without going into a view? Eg I want to run a function from a controller using jQuery when a button is clicked.